# Finding the last position of each column in data frame by Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have done some searching to  answer this question, but all I can not figure out how to do this:

I have a dataset which contains 185 rows and 30 columns. Not all of the rows have value. I want to look for the position of the last value on each column and take the index of that column. I am not sure how to do this operation as when I use the code below it gives me the length of the data frame not just that column :

```
len(data_exam['col'])
```

I would appreciate for any suggestion.

Also I want to make sure that if I want to read all the columns in a loop, does my following code would be a good choice or not! :

```
 list=[]
 for col in data:
    function which find the length of column
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain "not all the rows have value". Does this mean everything is blank following the value you're looking for? Please also post sample/reproducible data.

Comment: So, to be clear, if you had 10 columns and the first row only had values for the first 5 columns you would want the index of the fifth column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`last_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html) to find the index location of the last valid value in a given column.  There is also its twin, `first_valid_index`.

```
# Set-up sample data.
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))

df.iloc[2:, 0] = np.nan
df.iloc[4:, 1] = np.nan
>>> df
          A         B         C
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
2       NaN -0.151357 -0.103219
3       NaN  0.144044  1.454274
4       NaN       NaN  0.443863

# Solution to find index of last valid values per column.
>>> df.apply(lambda series: series.last_valid_index())
A    1  # <== Index of last valid data in column A.
B    3  # <== Index of last valid data in column B.
C    4  # <== Index of last valid data in column C.
dtype: int64
```

Comment: or, avoiding `lambda`: `df.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index)`.

Answer (score 6):

IIUC, you want the value of the last non-nan in each column:

```
df[::-1].bfill().iloc[0]
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,np.nan],'B':[1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],'C':[1,2,3,4,5]})

     A    B  C
0  1.0  1.0  1
1  2.0  NaN  2
2  3.0  NaN  3
3  4.0  NaN  4
4  NaN  NaN  5
```

Output:

```
A    4.0
B    1.0
C    5.0
Name: 4, dtype: float64
```

Comment: OP asked to find index of last value. _"I want to look for the position of the last value on each column and take the index of that column."_ Should probably read "index of that value".

Answer (score 2):

```
df.reset_index().melt('index').dropna().groupby('variable')['index'].max()
Out[487]: 
variable
A    3
B    0
C    4
Name: index, dtype: int64
```

Comment: You should use `last()` instead of `max()` to generalize for other indices (this will fail if the index is reversed, for example).  Also, using `melt`significantly degrades performance.